# Display single result from database where ID matches using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some trouble displaying a single field from the db based on an ID number.

I want to  trying to display the "C_Type_of_Referral" if the ID matches.  I am sure the code is a mess of crap but I am still at the VERY early stages of learning how to do things in mysql and php.

```
$query = "SELECT C_Type_of_Referral FROM Ctable WHERE C_ID = '70'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
list($C_Type_of_Referral) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Then I am trying to display the result using the code below:

```
echo ((isset ($_POST['C_Type_of_Referral']) && $_POST['C_Type_of_Referral'] == 'AS') || ($C_Type_of_Referral == 'AS'));
```

The code above returns the value of 1.

```
echo ($_POST['C_Type_of_Referral']);
```

The code above returns nothing.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've edit your post, `<?php` and `?>` are not needed in example code. Also, the curly brackets served no purpose (in this piece of code)

Comment: $_POST - gets you data submitted with a POST request. I thought you wanted to get something from the database? And if your C_ID is numeric, dont query it with a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start with: Use **mysqli** instead of mysql, especially when you are starting. Mysql is getting outdate, so start with the right one :)

```
$query = "SELECT C_Type_of_Referral FROM Ctable WHERE C_ID = 70 LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $fetch['C_Type_of_Referral']; // <- this is what you are looking for

if( $fetch['C_Type_of_Referral']=='AS'){ echo 'AdServices'; }
elseif( $fetch['C_Type_of_Referral']=='VS'){ echo 'VisServices'; }
else{ echo 'Nothing of the kind'; }
```

Things I've done:
- removed quotes arround `70`. Integers should not use quotes.
- Added 'limit 1'. This will speed things up in the long run. If you want 1 line, use limit 1
- Changed fetch_array to fetch_assoc ( you'll have to find out why yourself ;) )

Small note: keep table and columnnames lowercase, some systems might give you troubles when you use uppercase characters

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!  Very easy to follow and I can see why you have changed things!  That is the first part I was trying to do, now I need to also say if the result is "AS" then display "AdServices" OR if the result is "VS" then display "VisServices".

Comment: No problem, that's what the site is for. I've updated my answer, succes ermee :)